# When does ∫()=∫(())?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula, cauchy-riemann-equations

When does $Re(\int_Cf(z)dz) = \int_c Re(f(z)dz)$?

I genuinely have no idea where to even begin with this. I thought about letting $f$ be a function, such as $f = \frac{1}{z}$ but don't know how that would look different for each side of the equation? In other words, I guess my question is how does $Re$ change the equation?

Thank you!

Comment: Write $f=u+iv$ and $dz=dx+idy$ multiply term by term etc

Comment: @Conrad I get how you got (∫())=∫(−) but could you please explain how you got ∫(())=∫+? Thank you!

Comment: @Adam It depends on which integral you consider as the title has $\int_C Re(f(z))dz$ while the body has $\int_C Re(f(z)dz)$ and I think from here comes the confusion as the two are quite different - I will delete my comments as it seems they add to this confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is always true. That is literally the definition of integration of a complex valued 1-form. Namely, if $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are real valued 1-forms and $\omega = \omega_1 + i\omega_2$, then the definition is
$$\int_{C}\omega := \int_{C}\omega_1 + i\int_{C}\omega_2.$$
This is the only definition that ensures that integration is linear.

Edit: There is some confusion on the definition of the real part $\text{Re}(\omega)$ of a complex valued 1-form. A complex valued one form $\omega$ on an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an object of the form $\omega = f\,dx + g\,dy$, where $f, g : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$. In the question, we are interested in the case where $\omega = f\,dz$, where $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$, and $dz = dx + i\,dy$. Write $f = u + iv$ with $u, v : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. Then we have
$$f\,dz = (u + iv)(dx + i\,dy) = u\,dx - v\,dy + i(v\,dx + u\,dy).$$
The standard definitions of $\text{Re}$ and $\text{Im}$ of a 1-form yield
$$\text{Re}(f\,dz) = u\,dx - v\,dy,$$
$$\text{Im}(f\,dz) = v\,dx + u\,dy.$$
By linearity of integration, when you integrate $f \,dz$ you get
$$\int_{C} f\,dz = \int_{C}(u\,dx - v\,dy) + i\int_{C}(v\,dx + u\,dy).$$
Hence $\text{Re}(\int_{C}f\,dz) = \int_{C}\text{Re}(f\,dz)$ and $\text{Im}(\int_{C}f\,dz) = \int_{C}\text{Im}(f\,dz)$.

Comment: @coudy I was assuming that $c$ was a typo and was meant to be $C$.

Comment: @Conrad You are using the wrong definition of $\text{Re}$. It is incorrect to say $\text{Re}(iy \,dz) = \text{Re}(iy)\,dz$, because $dz = dx + i\,dy$ is a complex valued one-form. The correct value is $$\text{Re}(iy\,dz) = \text{Re}(iy(dx + i\,dy)) = \text{Re}(-y\,dy + iy\,dx) = -y\,dy.$$ Integrate this along the vertical segment from $0$ to $(0, 1)$, and you get $-\frac{1}{2}$ as expected.

Comment: as noted there is a confusion between the title and the body of the question so you are right if the integral in question is $\int_C Re(f(z)dz)$ (in other words you do $f(z)dz$ and take its real part, while I was talking about $\int_C Re(f(z))dz$ where you do first $\Re f$ and then take the result and integrate it $dz$ which is quite different; I deleted my comments since they only added to this confusion and I agree with your answer if the question asks what is in the body but not what is in the title as the two are quite different

Comment: @Conrad Ah I see. I can't even read the title. All the symbols are boxes.